# Zoho global variables or workaround for that

Tags: global-variables, zoho

I'm new to Zoho CRM. I need to show a warning on button press but only once for the first button press. This sounds really simple but yet I can't figure out how to do it in Zoho Creator as all variables seems to have local scope so I can't determine if the button was pressed before. I've been searching if there are global variables in Zoho but found only workarounds with creating another applications for that case.

I've also tried creating a field on my form and hiding it to pass some value there if the button was pressed so next time I can check this field but is not working for some reason.

In validation part I'm assigning new value to a field

```
warning_shown=true;
```

But on a form this checkbox remains unchecked and next time I press the button `warning_shown` equals `false`.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone interested, here is a reply I got on another forum that might help. Here is a link for that [topic](https://forums.zoho.com/topic/fill-the-field-from-validation-or-any-workaround-for-global-variables?reply=true)

It's not going to be possible to use the validation code section to display the message.

I was thinking you could have your hidden decision box field, and in the "On User Input" of the last field in the form you could use something like:

```
//remember to change field names accordingly
if !input.warning_shown
{
      alert "Message here!";
      input.warning_shown = true;
}
```

This would show the message after the last field is filled but before the button is clicked.